# I have uninstalled SVN Server by mistake. How do I proceed further?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

We have kept lot of important documents in our Tortoise SVN repository. We uninstalled the VisualSVN Server by mistake. I can see the Repositories folder at the earlier location.

Will re-installing the server solve the issue for us?

Comment: You can always back your data up, try to reinstall and see what happens. I see no reason why it shouldn't work, tho.

Comment: Yes, *definitely* take a copy of your repository first. Probably wise to use the same version of svn as before.

Comment: Thanks ... yes, I have backup. Will let you know what happens.

Comment: While you're at it, fix your server access so that someone can't "accidentally" uninstall critical software. It sounds like you have too many people with administrative access when they shouldn't - or your administrators aren't being terribly careful in how they're managing the server and just doing things haphazardly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your repositories and server settings are safe.

Just reinstall the VisualSVN Server selecting the same installation directory and port number. Reinstalling is a matter of of minutes, in fact.

**Note:** It's recommended to install the same version as you've uninstalled.

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry for not responding then, issue got solved by reinstalling the server.

Answer (score 0):

> Will re-installing the server solve the issue for us?

Yes, but you can use more easier way (because Visual SVN Server provides http-access to repositories, but file:/// protocol can be used without it):

If real repositories inside parent folder are present and not broken in some way **and** you have any SVN-client (TortoiseSVN is OK), you can work with repositories on local filesystem as usual, but use file:/// protocol in URL.

Sample: repository on `z:\Repo` path can be browsed|checkouted using `file:///Z:/Repo` URL

[image: Local Repository]

If you haven't svn-client here, you can copy repository as odinary directory on any other host (to *any* location) and use on this new host

Comment: file:/// access should *never* be used in a multi-user situation, nor over a network share.

Comment: @alroc - you mix WC on share and (RO) access to FSFS repo - it's nothing bad in reading repo from mapped drive. And *single-user* **checkout-only** from such repo is method of last resort for OP in his bad case